# Should I use the "nofollow" attribute for external links (for more link juice)?

Tags: seo, html, links, nofollow

My main question is: Should I use the "nofollow" attribute (rel="nofollow" inside links)?

My aim, of course, is to get my pages on my site better ranked by Google.

So what are the best practices here, in terms of increasing my ranking? Are my assumptions below right or wrong?

1. My first assumption is that the "nofollow" attribute should NOT be applied when I link to pages on my own site.
2. My second assumption is that the "nofollow" attribute should *probably* be applied whenever I link to external pages that I have no business relationship with.
3. My third assumption is that the "nofollow" attribute should *probably* NOT be used whenever I link to an external page that sells one of my books.

Example, point 2:
So in relation to point 2 above, say that I have a post on my site where I have links to Amazon for all the books that I am referencing in that article. Would adding a "nofollow" attribute to each of those Amazon links improve my page ranking? (Note that I am NOT an affiliate marketer.)

Example, point 3:
From my "Shop" page I am planning have a link to an external page (on Amazon, on Lulu, etc) where I will be selling my upcoming books. Would SKIPPING adding a "nofollow" attribute on such links then be improving my page ranking?

Comment: When you asked this at SO, I you suggested that it might be different than [How important is that we use REL="NOFOLLOW" in external links?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42289/how-important-is-that-we-use-rel-nofollow-in-external-links).  It still looks exactly the same to me.  You didn't make any changes to differentiate it.

Comment: I meant that it already was different enough to the old question to qualify. And I still think it is. So I'll just find some other forum where they allow new user questions. No big deal. Thanks for your input, in any case! Have a nice day!